# How to copy paste destination without using activate sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a problem with my macro, I run it from one sheet(A) and I need to copy cells from sheet(B) and paste it to sheet(C) but I could only make it changing sheets, there is any way to do that without activate sheets???

My macro:

```
enter code here
Sub VPL()

Dim j As Long, i As Long

For j = 1 To 9


' COPIAR/COLAR GERAÇÃO


' How to do this without activate sheets "Geração" and "Premissas"????

Sheets("Geração").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(20, 2 + j), Cells(31, 2 + j)).Select
Selection.Copy


Sheets("Premissas").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("Z20:AI31").Select
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
 Operation:=xlNone, _
 SkipBlanks:=False, _
 Transpose:=False


Sheets("Premissas").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("AL20:AL31").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
 Operation:=xlNone, _
 SkipBlanks:=False, _
 Transpose:=False


 ' COPIAR/COLAR PLD

For i = 1 To 2000

'The same problem here.

Sheets("PLD NE").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1 + i, 1), Cells(1 + i, 60)).Select
Selection.Copy


Sheets("Macro").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("AZ27").Select
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
 Operation:=xlNone, _
 SkipBlanks:=False, _
 Transpose:=False

'COPIAR/COLAR VPL

'The macro runs form Sheets("RESULTADO LEN") and I want only to be on this sheet.

Sheets("RESULTADO LEN").Activate  

Sheets(10).Cells(3 + i, 2 + j) = Sheets(5).Cells(35, 4).Value   'Ametista
Sheets(10).Cells(3 + i, 11 + j) = Sheets(5).Cells(62, 4).Value  'Borgo
Sheets(10).Cells(3 + i, 20 + j) = Sheets(5).Cells(89, 4).Value  'Caitite
Sheets(10).Cells(3 + i, 29 + j) = Sheets(5).Cells(116, 4).Value 'Dourados
Sheets(10).Cells(3 + i, 38 + j) = Sheets(5).Cells(143, 4).Value 'Espigão
Sheets(10).Cells(3 + i, 47 + j) = Sheets(5).Cells(170, 4).Value 'Maron
Sheets(10).Cells(3 + i, 56 + j) = Sheets(5).Cells(197, 4).Value 'Pelourinho
Sheets(10).Cells(3 + i, 65 + j) = Sheets(5).Cells(224, 4).Value 'Pilões
Sheets(10).Cells(3 + i, 74 + j) = Sheets(5).Cells(251, 4).Value 'Serra do espigão
Sheets(10).Cells(3 + i, 83 + j) = Sheets(6).Cells(36, 4).Value  'São Salvador

Next
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In the linked question above i found the Range.Copy command.

You can use it like this:

```
Sub CopyCells()
    Dim RngA As Range
    Set RngA = Sheets("A").Range("B1:C4")

    Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = "foo"
    RngA.Copy Sheets(1).Range("B1:C4")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

(untested)

With no selecting/activating:

```
Sub VPL()

Dim j As Long, i As Long, rng As Range
Dim rw As Range, col As Range
Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    For j = 1 To 9

        With wb.Sheets("Geração")
            Set rng = .Range(.Cells(20, 2 + j), .Cells(31, 2 + j)).Copy
        End With

        wb.Sheets("Premissas").Range("Z20:AI31,AL20:AL31").Value = rng.Value

        For i = 1 To 2000

            With wb.Sheets("PLD NE")
                Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1 + i, 1), .Cells(1 + i, 60))
            End With

            wb.Sheets("Macro").Range("AZ27").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, _
                            rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value

            wb.Sheets("RESULTADO LEN").Activate

            Set rw = wb.Sheets(10).Rows(3 + i)
            Set col = wb.Sheets(5).Columns(4)

            With rw
                .Cells(2 + j).Value = col.Cells(35).Value   'Ametista
                .Cells(11 + j) = col.Cells(62).Value  'Borgo
                .Cells(20 + j) = col.Cells(89).Value  'Caitite
                '...etc
            End With

        Next i
    Next j

End Sub
```